# How to Output int from char in JAVA after storing it

Tags: java

I am seeing a tutorial on udemy and there the instructor says that we can store the integer variable in the char data type. But when I try to print the value ... nothing shows up

I tried assigning the "char one" value  to integer variable and then get the output from int variable,It works but why can not I use the char to output the value

```
 public static void main(String[] args) { 
     char one = 10;
     System.out.println(one);
 }
```

Comment: have a look at the ASCII table and see what 10 represents with regards to char and it will make sense. For example, to print the letter A you would use the value 65.

Answer (score 2):

In Java `char` type is an `int`, therefore they can be converted `char <-> int`.

When you print an `int` - you get an integer number. When you print `char` - you get an [ASCII](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) character. `char ch = 10` - is not printable character.

```
char ch = 'A';
System.out.println(ch);   // print 'A'
int code = ch;
System.out.println(code); // print 65 - ASCII code of 'A'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the ASCII table you would see that the character ***10*** represents the ***newline character.***

[image]

This can be proved by the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     char one = 10;
     //no newline added by print, but println adds a newline implicitly
     System.out.print("Test");  
     System.out.print(one);
     System.out.print("Test");
}
```

The output is:

```
Test
Test
```

Although I used `System.out.print` a ***newline*** was still added in the output after the first `Test`. So you see something was actually printed.

Furthermore, when you pass a `char` to the `System.out.println()` the `char` is converted to its `String` representation as per the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) by invoking the `String.valueOf(char)` as `char` is a primitive.

For Objects when you pass a reference in the `System.out.println()` the `toString()` method of the object would be called to get its String representation.

If you change the value to `char one = 65` you would see the letter `A` printed.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [ASCII Table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html), you can see the value of `10` is  `LF` which is a new line.  If you print this alone, it will appear to be doing nothing because it is *just* a new line.

However if you modify the code a bit to print some actual characters on both side of the `LF` char:

```
char c1 = 70;
System.out.print(c1);
char one = 10;
System.out.print(one);
char c2 = 71;
System.out.print(c2);
```

This will output:

```
F
G
```

On separate lines due to the newline in between, without it they would have printed on the same line.

Additionally you can see on that table `70` corresponds with `F`, and `71` with `G`.

**Note:**  Java does not technically use `ASCII`, but rather a different encoding depending on your environment(commonly `UTF-16` or `ISO-8859-1`), however, the characters are usually equivalent to `ASCII` for the amount of values the `ASCII` table contains (a superset).  For example `char c1 = 202` will print `Ê` for me, which is not an `ASCII` value.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answers, if you want to output the int value from the variable "one", a cast would work:

```
char one = 10;
System.out.println((int) one);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting your output and drawing the wrong conclusion.

A `char` is a UTF-16 code unit. UTF-16 is a character encoding for the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set. UTF-16 encodes a Unicode codepoint with one or two UTF-16 code units. Typically, if it might be two code units, you'd use `String` or `char[]` instead of `char`. But if your codepoint is known to take only one UTF-16 code unit, you could use `char`.

The codepoint you are using is U+000A 'LINE FEED (LF)'. It does take one UTF-16 code unit `\u000a`, which is convertible from the integer value `0xa` or `10`. If you inspect your output carefully, you'll "see". Perhaps adding output before and after would help.